# sscanf in arduino is only catching last int

Tags: arduino, serial-port, arduino-ide

I'm trying to send some numbers over a serial port from my computer to my arduino and I'm using sscanf to parse the numbers from the string. The detection system works fine but for some reason sscanf is only grabbing the last number from the message. Here is the code below that is failing. Red, Green and Blue are uint8_t variables.

```
else if (sscanf(message, "(%u, %u, %u)\n", &red, &green, &blue) == 3)
  {
    sprintf(debug, "got (%d, %d, %d)\n", red, green, blue);
    Serial.println(message);
    Serial.print(debug);
```

This code runs and prints the following if i send "(1, 2, 3)"

```
(1, 2, 3)

got (0, 0, 3)
```

why is it parsing only the last number?

**EDIT**

Here is the rest of the serial reading code

```
while (Serial.available() > 0)
{
  message[str_postion] = Serial.read();
  if (message[str_postion] == '\n')
  {
    message[str_postion + 1] = '\0';
    str_postion = 0;
    if (message[0] == 'T')
    {
      Serial.print("GREEN!\n");
    }
    else if (sscanf(message, "(%d, %d, %d)\n", &red, &green, &blue) == 3)
    {
      sprintf(debug, "got (%d, %d, %d)\n", red, green, blue);
      Serial.println(message);
      Serial.print(debug);
      target_color[0] = red;
      target_color[1] = green;
      target_color[2] = blue;
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.print("PARSE\n");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    str_postion++;
  }
}
```

Comment: probably your error is somewhere else.. I tried your code (I just removed the `\n` at the end of the format string because I had to test for another char, since my emulated serial monitor did not support new lines) and it worked as expected (`got (1, 2, 3)` when I sent `(1, 2, 3)`). Try showing us also your reading functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the data types I was using for the color variables. For some reason sscanf didnt like uint8_t, when i switched them to uint16_t it worked fine.